# Fixed middle Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I'm trying to build a personal website example,

```css
body{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
    margin: 0;
}
.wraper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);    
}
.box1{
order: 1;
height: 100vh;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 10% 60% 15% 15%;
border: 1px black solid;
grid-gap: 10px;
background-image: url("b.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center ;
background-size: 210vh 200vh;
}
.box1>div{
  
}
.logo{

   
}
.logo>img{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.chancing-word{   
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 13%;
    color: white;
}
.down_writing{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
    color: white;
}
.arrow_down{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid white;
     border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.arrow1{
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
.box2{
order: 2;
display: block;
position: sticky;
z-index: 1;




}
.box::before{
    
}
.box3{
order: 3;
}
.box4{
order:4;
}
header{
    background-color: rgba(70, 127, 165, 0.123);
    
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
.navbar { 
    
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;   
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: flex-end;  
}
    
    
.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
    
}
.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    border: cornflowerblue thin 0,1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}






.chancing-word::after{
    content: "Follow your dreams";
    animation: textanim 10s linear infinite; 
}
@keyframes textanim {
    25%{
        content: "It is never too late";
    }
    50%{
        content: "You can do it, too"
    }
    75%{
        content: "You, I`m talking to YOU"
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="personal webpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Latecoder</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="box1">
            <div class="logo"><img  src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"></div>
            <div class="chancing-word"> </div>
            <div class=down_writing>Hello, over here</div>
            <div class="arrow1"><i class="arrow_down"></i></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="box2">

                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="services">Services</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="Works">Works</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></div>
                        
                    
                </nav>
            
        </div>
        <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis voluptas minus dolor unde dicta aliquid odio ut temporibus, aspernatur distinctio nam voluptatibus placeat illum impedit, quisquam recusandae rem sapiente libero.</div>
        <div class="box4"></div>
    </div>
    
       
    <footer>

    </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I try to stick the navigation bar on the middle of the website and after I scrolled down, I want the navigation bar to stay on the top. Also, I want to remove the scroll bar on left if it is possible.

I gave enough detail
I gave enough detail
I gave enough detail

Comment: Do you want the .navbar to move throughout the site?

Comment: Yes, I want to move throughout the site after I pass that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my example. I made the navbar moveable. Your navbar will only move within the div "box2", because it is because of the current structure of your site. In order for the navbar to move throughout the site, you need to move the navbar outside the div "box2".

```css
body{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
    margin: 0;
}
.wraper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);    
}
.box1{
order: 1;
height: 100vh;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 10% 60% 15% 15%;
border: 1px black solid;
grid-gap: 10px;
background-image: url("b.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center ;
background-size: 210vh 200vh;
}
.box1>div{
  
}
.logo{

   
}
.logo>img{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.chancing-word{   
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 13%;
    color: white;
}
.down_writing{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
    color: white;
}
.arrow_down{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid white;
     border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
.arrow1{
   text-align: center;
   padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
.box2{
order: 2;
display: block;
position: sticky;
z-index: 1;




}
.box::before{
    
}
.box3{
order: 3;
}
.box4{
order:4;
}
header{
    background-color: rgba(70, 127, 165, 0.123);
    
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
.navbar { 
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;   
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: flex-end;  
}
    
    
.navbar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
    
}
.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    border: cornflowerblue thin 0,1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.chancing-word::after{
    content: "Follow your dreams";
    animation: textanim 10s linear infinite; 
}
@keyframes textanim {
    25%{
        content: "It is never too late";
    }
    50%{
        content: "You can do it, too"
    }
    75%{
        content: "You, I`m talking to YOU"
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="personal webpage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Latecoder</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="box1">
            <div class="logo"><img  src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"></div>
            <div class="chancing-word"> </div>
            <div class=down_writing>Hello, over here</div>
            <div class="arrow1"><i class="arrow_down"></i></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="box2">

                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="services">Services</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="Works">Works</a></div>
                    <div class="nav_buttons"><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></div>
                        
                    
                </nav>
            
        </div>
        <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis voluptas minus dolor unde dicta aliquid odio ut temporibus, aspernatur distinctio nam voluptatibus placeat illum impedit, quisquam recusandae rem sapiente libero.</div>
        <div class="box4"></div>
    </div>
    
       
    <footer>

    </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why this `position: sticky` command doesn't work without `top` command?

Comment: @Latecoder, the `top` parameter is used to adjust the indent from the top of the screen when the object is moving. For example, if you set the `top:10px`, then when you move the object will recede 10 pixels from the top of the screen.